# Excel 2016 VBA copy picture from sheet and autofit in textbox on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, image, textbox, autosize

I have a picture "Picture 1" in the top left corner of sheet "Logo".
This came there thru another macro.
Now I would like a macro to copy "Picture 1" and paste it in textbox "TextboxLogo" on sheet "Voorblad".
The picture should autosize to 90% of the textbox height and centered in the middle both vertical and horizontal.

This is the code I've got so far:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim picture As Shape

Sheets("Logo").Activate
picture = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
Sheets("Voorblad").Visible = True
With Sheets("Voorblad").Shapes("TextBoxLogo").Fill
    .Visible = True
    .UserPicture picture
    .TextureTile = True
    .RotateWithObject = True
End With

End Sub
```

I have to use a textbox due to a picture overlapping all the cells.

When I run this I get runtime error 91, object variable or with block variable not set.
I've searched this forum and google but no succes.

I hope I get lucky this way

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> Dim picture As Shape
> ```

`Shape` is an object type, `picture` is an object variable.

> ```
> picture = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
> ```

You can't assign an object reference like this. What the runtime error is telling you, is that the `Set` keyword is missing.

```
Set picture = ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
```

---

That said you don't need to do `Sheets("Logo").Activate`.

```
Set picture = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Logo").Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
```

Or, if the `"Logo"` sheet exists at compile-time in the workbook that's running the macro, set its `(Name)` property to, say, `LogoSheet`, and then you can do this:

```
Set picture = LogoSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
```

If it exists in the workbook that's running the macro, but is only created at run-time, you don't need the `ActiveWorkbook` either:

```
Set picture = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Logo").Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 1"))
```

---

If the shape `Picture 1` is a single shape, the `.Range(Array(...))` stuff is superfluous, and this could be all you need (assuming you set the `(Name)` property of that worksheet to be `LogoSheet`:

```
Set picture = LogoSheet.Shapes("Picture 1")
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, made the changes but the second part of the macro still errors when trying to add the picture to the textbox (runtime error 13 type mismatch)

Comment: @JensDamen per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.userpicture), seems `Fill.UserPicture` expects a path/filename, not a `Shape` object. That would be your *type mismatch*.

Comment: any idea how to change this? I tried googling add a shape inside a shape with vba but nothing seems to fit my needs

Comment: That would be a rather different question than understanding why runtime error 91 gets thrown when you don't use the `Set` keyword to assign an object variable. You'll need to get the picture you want on disk [somehow](https://analystcave.com/excel-image-vba-save-range-workbook-image/), and load it using the file name.

Comment: So I changed the way it will work to a manual picture selector when running the macro. but now the code refuses to accept .png files and 50% of my logo database are .png files.

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question specifically about this :)